# Can't open some applications.. error while loading shared libraries: libicudata.so.56: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: 20.04, shared-library

Cant open some applications such as qbittorrent, nomacs

getting error the following
error while loading shared libraries: libicudata.so.56: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

You are probably doing something wrong. Moreover you mention libicu56 which was never available for both Debian and Ubuntu distributions.

Really, the packages are available in official Ubuntu repositories - see [*qbittorrent*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/qbittorrent) and [*nomacs*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/nomacs).

To install them in regular deb/APT based way use commands below:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qbittorrent nomacs
```